# Java Magic Square - Sum Column and Sum Row Errors

Tags: java, arrays, methods, compiler-errors, magic-square

I've been assigned a school assignment to make and check for a 'Magic Square' in a 2d array generated by the user in a N*N matrix.

So far, I have gotten most of the code right (I have tested each method individually). However, I am unable to correct two final errors that keep popping up within my 'sumColumn' and 'sumRow' methods. Here is my code for the two aforementioned methods:

```
public static int sumColumn(int[][] square, int columnNumber)
{
    int sum = 0 ;
    for (int j = 0; j < square.length ; j++)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < square.length; i++)
        {
            sum = sum + square[i][j] ;
        }
    }                        
    return sum ;
}

public static int sumRow(int[][] square, int rowNumber)
{
    int sum = 0 ;
    for (int i = 0; i < square.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < square.length; j++)
        {
            sum = sum + square[i][j] ;
        }
    }
    return sum ;
}
```

And here is the output along with the error that appears upon calling from the main method:

```
Please enter a value for N:
1
Please enter 1 numbers: 
1
This is the square you input:
+-+
|1|
+-+
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
The method sumRow(int[][], int) in the type MagicSquares is not applicable for the arguments (int[][]) at squares.MagicSquares.validMagicSquare(MagicSquares.java:105)
The method sumColumn(int[][], int) in the type MagicSquares is not applicable for the arguments (int[][]) at squares.MagicSquares.main(MagicSquares.java:167)
```

Some fiddling with 'sumRow' and 'sumColumn' will instead yield another error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
rowNumber cannot be resolved to a variable at squares.MagicSquares.validMagicSquare(MagicSquares.java:105)
colNumber cannot be resolved to a variable at squares.MagicSquares.main(MagicSquares.java:167)
```

Any help would be much appreciated in resolving this issue! Thanks!

PS: I've only started programming last month, so be kind :3

Edit: here is the method which checks if each row, column and main and secondary diagonals are equal to make a Magic Square.

```
boolean status = true ;
    int sum = sumDiagonal(square) ;
    if (sumSecondaryDiagonal(square) != sum)
    {
        status = false ;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int row = 0; (row < square.length) && status; row ++)
        {
            if (sum != sumRow(square, square.length))
            {
                status = false ;
            }
        }
        for (int col = 0; (col < square.length) && status; col ++)
        {
            if (sum != sumColumn(square, square.length))
            {
                status = false ;
            }
        } 
    }
    return status;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `sumColumn` method expects two arguments:

1. `int[][] square`
2. `int columnNumber`

In your main method, it seems you are just providing a single argument, the `int[][]`, and you forgot to include the columnNumber as a second argument.

Same applies to the `sumRow` method.

I made the above findings based on the error message you posted:

`The method sumRow(int[][], int) in the type MagicSquares is not applicable for the arguments (int[][]) at squares.MagicSquares.validMagicSquare(MagicSquares.java:105)`

It says that, in your MagicSquares.java file, line number 105, you invoke `sumRow` method. It further indicates that `(The method sumRow(int[][], int) in the type MagicSquares)`, the method you implemented, can not be used/is not applicable for a call with arguments `(int[][])`, at line 105.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Yes, I am unsure on how to include 'int rowNumber' and 'int columnNumber' into their respective methods. As per my assignments rules, I cannot get rid of these variables, nor can I alter the main method in any way ):

Comment: I am not suggesting for you to get rid of them. Instead, in your main method, you should include this argument, example: int x = sumRow(square, 5)

Comment: You're welcome. Now to make everything complete, mark an answer as "Accepted" :)

Answer (score 0):

Your shown code does not have syntax errors.

But your exception:

> The method **sumRow(int[][], int)** in the type MagicSquares is not applicable for the **arguments (int[][])** at squares.MagicSquares.validMagicSquare(MagicSquares.java:105)

You don't make the right call to `sumColumn` and `sumRow` when calling them:

```
int[][] matrix = // your matrix;
sumRow(matrix);     // bad call
sumRow(matrix, 1);  // good call!!!!
```

But actually, if you check the methods you dont use `columnNumber` and `rowNumber` so if you want to sum all columns / rows redeclare your methods as now are written like this:

```
public static int sumAllColumns(int[][] square)
public static int sumAllRows(int[][] square)
```

And make sure 2nd loop iterates over columns!!!

```
for (int j = 0; j < square[0].length; j++)
```

> **I MUST not change** the heading of any methods.

So, just use methods already existing, but make sure you use the `columnNumber` and `rowNumber` variables. If method description is the right one, you only need to sum given row / column, so no nested loops needed.

```
public static int sumColumn(int[][] square, int columnNumber) {
    int sum = 0 ;
    for (int i = 0; i < square.length; i++)
        sum = sum + square[columnNumber][i] ;
    return sum ; 
}

public static int sumRow(int[][] square, int rowNumber)
{
    int sum = 0 ;
    for (int i = 0; i < square[0].length; i++)
        sum = sum + square[i][rowNumber] ;
    return sum ;
}
```

**[Check here a working DEMO](https://ideone.com/2b5S4R)**.

## ADD ON's

**SAFE CHECKING:** as long as you can give any `columnNumber` or `rowNumber` the methods can throw an **`IndexOutOfBounds`** exception.
**SOLUTION**
To avoid this, check if the given index in inside the array.

**HUMANIZING**: To sum first row or column you must give 0 value. So in order to make user refer to rows and columns in a *human* way (column 1 if the first one)
**SOLUTION**
To avoid this use given row / column - 1 in your methods AND checks:

```
public static int sumColumn(int[][] square, int columnNumber) {
    // humanize
    columnNumber = columnNumber - 1;
    // safe check
    if ((columnNumber) > square.length) 
        return 0;

    int sum = 0 ;
    for (int i = 0; i < square.length; i++)
        sum = sum + square[columnNumber][i] ;
    return sum ; 
}

public static int sumRow(int[][] square, int rowNumber)
{
    // humanize
    rowNumber = rowNumber - 1;
    // safe check
    if ((rowNumber) > square[0].length) 
        return 0;

    int sum = 0 ;
    for (int i = 0; i < square[0].length; i++)
        sum = sum + square[i][rowNumber] ;
    return sum ;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply :)

Yeah, getting rid of both 'int columnNumber' and 'int rowNumber' would solve the problem. Unfortunately, per my assignment's rules, I cannot change the heading of any methods (including main method) grrr

I HAVE to use int columnNumber and rowNumber in my methods ):
I'm struggling to incorporate these two variables into both their respective methods as they seem 'redundant'.

Comment: Nice code! But my matrix can range from a 2*2 matrix to an infinite number @_@. Parameter must be in such a way where it would sum up the rows individually for any given number of N.

Comment: that is what my code does, if no, please [check the demo](https://ideone.com/2b5S4R).... you can insert there any 2d array you need to sum with a column, what my code does not check is valid values of `rowNumber` and `columnNumber` so if you insert a 5x5 array and try to sum column 6 will throw `IOOBException`

Comment: Hmmm, its different for my code. I have edited my question to show you what I mean. I'm not sure how to exactly explain it in words.  ><

Comment: did you checked the demo? do you know how to get the value that a method returns? why you say *its different for my code* ??? your code must have 2 methods to sum a given column or row... that's what my 2 last methods do.... if you don't understand something just say it... but **this does not work** or **in my code is different** are not giving us any clue about your problem.

Comment: Yes I checked the demo. After looking more closely, I tweaked around with the method that was receiving the sums. The program seems to be working as intended for now. Thanks for all your help :))

Comment: great to hear that @Khai. English is not my mother language and I sometimes have dificulties. As I suspect this is a homework... just one more tip... make your methods safe checked as in the last update.

Comment: After checking add on... And as this is your first StackOverflow question you must know: if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot. Sorry and thanks for the reminder.